# switch has problems with logical arguments

Tags: r, switch-statement, boolean

Apparently, switch has problems with logical arguments, and it can't evaluate on `FALSE`.

```
> switch(T, "TRUE"=10, "FALSE"=50)
[1] 10
> switch(F, "TRUE"=10, "FALSE"=50)
(No return value)
```

I know, for a T/F value I can use if/else but the problem with switch is a separate issue. It leads to even more weird things like

```
> switch(2, "TRUE"=10, "FALSE"=50, "2"=200)
[1] 50
> switch(2, "TRUE"=10, "FALSE"=50, 2=200)
Error: unexpected '=' in "switch(2, "TRUE"=10, "FALSE"=50, 2="
Error during wrapup: argument "fun" is missing, with no default
```

Why does this happen, and is it a bug or feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`?switch` says

> EXPR: an expression evaluating to a number or a character string

If you give it something else as `EXPR`, R will do the least invasive coercion possible to convert `EXPR` to a number or character string; in this case, the logical value gets converted to numeric. The problem is that when `F`/`FALSE` is coerced to numeric, it becomes 0, which selects *none* of the options.  It's a hack, but you *could* use

```
a <- FALSE
switch(a+1, "FALSE"=10, "TRUE"=50)  ## 10
a <- TRUE
switch(a+1, "FALSE"=10, "TRUE"=50)  ## 50
```

... but you would have to remember to put the options in FALSE/TRUE order (the labels are *ignored*).  I think this is A Bad Idea because it's tricky/non-obvious.  The idiomatic R, I think, would be

```
if (a) 50 else 10
```

(this may seem too tricky, but is actually preferable to `ifelse()` for scalar comparisons; you could use `ifelse()` without losing much if you and your co-workers find it more readable)

In your second example (`switch(2, "TRUE"=10, "FALSE"=50, "2"=200)`), you gave `switch()` an integer so R selects by position (the second option has value 50). In your third example (`switch(2, "TRUE"=10, "FALSE"=50, 2=200)`), `2` is not a valid name for an argument.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed something similar myself, i.e. to return a different value for `TRUE`, `FALSE` and (logical) `NA`. Another workable option is to explicitly convert the logical scalar input to character.

```r
switch_fun <- function(x) {
  switch(
    as.character(x),
    `TRUE` = "TRUE!",
    `FALSE` = "FALSE!",
    "NA!"
  )
}

switch_fun(TRUE)
#> [1] "TRUE!"
switch_fun(FALSE)
#> [1] "FALSE!"
switch_fun(NA)
#> [1] "NA!"
```